# Bug on legend of scatter plot with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have a problem with the legend in a scatter plot using pgfkeys. 
The color of the halfsquare sybol in the legend is different from the color defined in the plot, as show in the MWE bellow.

How can I correct this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \pgfplotsset{
            height=6cm, 
            scatter/classes={%
                    a={mark=square,draw=blue},%
                    b={mark=triangle,draw=red},%
                    c={mark=o,draw=orange},
                    d={mark=diamond,draw=green},
                    e={mark=pentagon,draw=magenta},
                    f={mark=halfsquare*,cyan,draw=cyan}
                    },
        }
        \tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=2},
                }
        \def\ec{2cm}
        % this is the leftmost y axis
        \begin{axis}[        
            xmin=0,xmax=1,%--- CF
            xshift=0,%-- CF
            width=1.8cm,
            hide x axis,
            axis y line*=left,
            ymin=25, ymax=27.5,
            ytick distance=0.5,
            title={$V_{max}$ (V)},
            legend style={at={(3,0.5)},anchor=west}
        ]
        \addplot+ [
            only marks,
            %mark=ball,
            scatter,% enable scatter
            scatter src=explicit symbolic,% the "color data"
                ]
            table[meta=label] {PlotV.dat};
            \legend{a,b,c,d,e,f}
        \end{axis}


     \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the MWE code]

Comment: Welcome! How many users do you think will have `PlotV.dat`, and how is `halfsquare*` defined? Please make your example self-contained.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, while I agree on the principle of your comment, the `mark=halfsquare*`  is defined according to the `pgfplots` manual (actually part of tikz library `plotmarks`)

Comment: @BambOo Yes, thanks! I found this meanwhile, too, and think that the code for that mark in `pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex` may not be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that does not have the problem. The cleaner way may be to rewrite the code for that mark in `pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex` but at least the following is a workaround. Sadly I had to make up data.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\begin{filecontents*}{PlotV.dat}
x y label 
0.1 0.15 a 
0.45 0.27 b 
0.02 0.17 c 
0.06 0.1 d
0.9 0.5 e 
0.5 0.3 f 
0.85 0.52 a 
0.12 0.05 b 
0.73 0.45 c 
0.53 0.25 d 
0.76 0.5 e 
0.55 0.32 f
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \pgfplotsset{
            height=6cm, 
            scatter/classes={%
                    a={mark=square,draw=blue},%
                    b={mark=triangle,draw=red},%
                    c={mark=o,draw=orange},%
                    d={mark=diamond,draw=green},%
                    e={mark=pentagon,draw=magenta},%
                    f={mark=halfsquare*,cyan,mark options={cyan,scale=2}}%
                    },
        }
        \tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=2},
                }
        \def\ec{2cm}
        % this is the leftmost y axis
        \begin{axis}[        
            xmin=0,xmax=1,%--- CF
            xshift=0,%-- CF
            width=1.8cm,
            hide x axis,
            axis y line*=left,
            %ymin=25, ymax=27.5,
            ytick distance=0.5,
            title={$V_\mathrm{max}$ (V)},
            legend style={at={(3,0.5)},anchor=west}
        ]
        \addplot+ [
            only marks,
            %mark=ball,
            scatter,% enable scatter
            scatter src=explicit symbolic,% the "color data"
                ]
            table[meta=label] {PlotV.dat};
            \legend{a,b,c,d,e,f}
        \end{axis}


     \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well done ! It's funny that you say *sadly I had to make up data*, it doesn't seem to require much effort for you to solve `tikz` questions, so I guess it's a way to force you to work a bit lol

Comment: @BambOo The main challenge in this answer was indeed to find some data that can be used here but the answer is far from perfect.  To be honest, I do not know what the cleanest way is, but it may be to rewrite parts of `pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex`. Some of the things there appear at the first sight redundant.

Comment: I guess that coul become an issue on the `pgfplots` bug tracker

Comment: @BambOo Maybe. Or I am missing something obvious. The author of these marks is indicated in the file, so maybe one could contact them. (BTW, did you check out the `planets` package. Soon you may be able to create your avatar with LaTeX. The cats have [already claimed a planet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07xRh.png) ;-)

Comment: Nice idea ! Just updated my avatar !

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. Sorry for forgetting to include the data in my MWE.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, I am pretty sure the author is not available any more and if he would, he would allow us to modify the marks (he is a former student of mine). So if you have cleaner implementations of the `plotmarks`, please add an issue to the tracker with your suggestions.